# <Link> Replace not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a full site in React. I'm using the `<HashRouter>` to render my app. Throughout the site you will see a navigation menu that uses `<Link>`s to take you to different pages.

One of the pages in my site is a shop, the URL for which is `/Shop`.

When you click on a product in the shop it uses `<Link>` to append the product name to the end of the current URL - `/Shop/Product` - and renders the corresponding information.

If you are looking at a product and you try to navigate to a different page it only replaces the last entry, *even with `replace={true}`*. So if I'm currently at `/Shop/Product` and I try to navigate to `/Contact`, the URL changes to `/Shop/Contact`.

Am I misunderstanding how `replace` is supposed to work? Or am I doing something incorrectly? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: React Router's `<Link>` has the 'to' property, are you using that for navigation? Because that takes an absolute path not a relative one so it should replace the entire URL. Could you maybe add some code showing the router and your links?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use something like this:

```
<Link to="Contact" />
```

It will only change the last piece of the URL because it's a relative path, so if you were at `/Shop/Something` it would change to `/Shop/Contact`

You probably want to use the absolute path instead:

```
<Link to="/Contact" />
```

--

The replace vs push route is a different thing. If you think of your route history as an array:

```
[
  '/Shop/Item',
  '/Shop/Item2'
]
```

`push` will append to the list, and `replace` will replace the last index

Comment: Thanks this works! And thank you for that info, I'm still very new to react router and routing in general.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot, without this my URL appended the link to rather than replacing it.